# Callback does not work when i use fetch() method on backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to make work the example of backbonetutorials. I am not able to throw a callback when the method fetch().

```
$(document).ready(function() {



var Timer = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : 'timeserver/',
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        email: ''
    }
});
var timer = new Timer({id:1});
timer.fetch({
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success')
   },
   fail: function(model, response) {
       alert('fail');
   },
   sync: function(data) {
        alert('sync')
   }
});

});
```

The ajax request it has been threw. But does not work at all. Because any alert its dispatched.

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `fail` with `error` in your callbacks and get rid of `sync`.

Answer (score 3):

`sync` and `fail` aren't valid callbacks. `fetch` uses the standard [jQuery XHR object's options](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/); there's `success`, `error`, and `complete`.

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/ccamarat/sGJy4/

Comment: Thanks @Kelsadita; the original answer didn't make much sense :)